# How to debug service-worker javascript-code in Firefox 70

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, service-worker

I created a simple [service-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers) (with fetch and activate events).
Those events are called as expected and everything seems to be OK so far.

But how to debug the service-worker javscript-code in Firefox 70?